# could i close an app whit list item in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpL5D.png)

so could i close my app by clicking the item "Keluar"(equals with close) when i click it?
this is my if case which is default from when i made the nav-drawer activity

```
 int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        mwebView.loadUrl("http://siavo.dipotrading.com");
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_kolam) {

        mwebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.94.2/final/displaydiskon.php");
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_pantai) {

        mwebView.loadUrl("http://siavo.dipotrading.com");
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_transaksi) {

        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        mwebView.loadUrl("http://siavo.dipotrading.com");
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_keluar) {
        //what should i put here for closing the app?
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://siavo.dipotrading.com");
    }
```

Comment: you want to close the app or the current activity?

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't really understand the difference since i didnt create any new activity and only using MainActivity.java. and both of finish() and system.exit(0) are working just fine.
if you dont mind could you tell me the difference between close the activity and app? just for the reference

Comment: @wilape in your case you have only single activity so both can work finish() or system.exit(0)
in any application there may be multiple activity depend on the requirement. suppose if u start activity A and from A activity you pass the intent to activity B and now you want to close the activity B and want that your activity A must be remain at open state at that time you can use finish(); to close the activity.If there are many activity is in open state and you want to close all the activity or close the application at that time you can use the system.exit(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to close the current activity use

```
finish();
```

want to exit from the application use

> System.exit(0);

use that like

```
if (id == R.id.nav_keluar) {
   System.exit(0);
 }
```

if u want to close the activity from the fragment:

```
 getActivity().finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()` on your `Activity`.

```
   if (id == R.id.nav_keluar) {
        MyAcitivityName.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` to exit from application.
**Use:**

```
if (id == R.id.nav_keluar) {
    finish();
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
if (id == R.id.nav_keluar) {
    //what should i put here for closing the app?
    mwebView.loadUrl("http://siavo.dipotrading.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

call **finish()** from Activity.
call **getActivity().finish()** from fragment.

By the way, use **switch case** here.

Comment: why did you suggested using switch case? because i only edit the default from android studio and if switch case are better i will use it. thank you